# How css link make hash code for front end browser

Tags: javascript, css, html

My question is , some times when I inspect some browser then seen there css link with hash code/ encrypted , not exact traceable . How it done for user ? How it encrypted ? Is there any special process ?

Here I  uploaded an image with red box where example is  shown .

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: There are multiple possible reasons that could explain that, could you provide a link for your example so we can have a look at the code?

Comment: This looks more like "Has a filename generated by a computer" then "is encrypted".

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/strategies-for-cache-busting-css/#article-header-id-5 This helpes to prevent problems with cached files. It istn't really a hashing in terms of security. Some frameworks and CMSystems do that after any css change you submit